# Sharing parts of the file system with compute nodes in a Beowulf cluster

Tags: nfs, cluster

We're using Scyld Clusterware (a Beowulf cluster), and I can never remember how to configure which parts of the shared file system are visible to the compute nodes. Which files need be configured, and how do I reload the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This documentation](http://gilgamesh.cheme.cmu.edu/scyld-doc/administration-guide/nfs.html) is helpful. You have to modify these two files:

- `/etc/exports`
- `/etc/beowulf/fstab`

Then refresh the exports with this command:

```
/usr/sbin/exportfs -a
```

Reboot each node with this command, replacing 0 with the node number:

```
bpctl -S 0 -R
```